# Design issue in Android Enthusiasts

Tags: bug, design

I have noticed a design issue in [Android Enthusiasts site](https://android.stackexchange.com/) in [innerpage](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/59282/how-to-add-a-contact-to-people-from-hangouts) when we hover on Upvote or downvote some weird things happening see images below

[image]

[image]

I have noticed [Jin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/147574/jin) wrote [Pulse Animation](http://pages.citebite.com/f4j3l8l7w0tpl) but it should actually work in this [way](http://pages.citebite.com/y4t3j8u7h1eqm).

**UPDATE**

As *eldarerathis* said it is occurring because of old version of firefox I updated my firefox and now the issue has been solved.

Comment: Which OS and browser are you using?

Comment: Linux Mint OS took screenshots from Mozilla.

Comment: What versions specifically?

Comment: Linux Mint `17 Qiana`
Mozilla `35.0.1`

Comment: Firefox 35 is [no longer officially supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/150283) because it is 2 versions old. You'll probably need to upgrade and re-test in order for your bug report to be acted upon.